# Using Word automation in C# I want to change the path which the next Save button will refer to

Tags: ms-word, office-automation

I have an application which creates and opens a document in Word.  The user can modify the document and then save it again, but I don't want the user to be prompted via Word to save it in the location from which it was loaded - I want to set the path to which the document should be saved (if any) to another path.

I'm not using automation to show a Save as dialog - it's the Word "Save" button that will be pressed, and so I want to set some sort of global default "saves as" location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, quite simple but not very good naming on Microsoft's part (but let's be forgiving, they have a huge object there).  Anyway, here's the code (where *Application* is the Word Application object defined in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word PIA):

```
Application.ChangeFileOpenDirectory("C:\\SampleFor\\StackOverflow");
```